# Pocketsphinx Android Multiple Keyword Spotting

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I have the Pocketsphinx Android demo (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) running perfectly by using the `setKws` function, but how would I go about having multiple keywords. I have played around with using JSGF, but it seems like the implemented keyword spotting is more efficient as well as I need the ability to have the keywords be dynamic and though it seems that you can have dynamic JSGF (but haven't figured out how), I thought there must be a better way to just slightly alter the current implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what your question is about?

Comment: @nikolas How would I extend the pocket sphinx android demo to recognize multiple keywords?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recognizing multiple keywords using PocketSphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx)

Comment: Do you mind helping me? I am trying to simply recognize the word "hello". Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388720/cant-start-service-speech-recog

Comment: have you solved your issue??