# Setting treshhold in grammar-file of PocketSphinx keyword detection

Tags: java, android, pocketsphinx

i`m trying to do exactly what the author of this thread did/solved:

[Recognizing multiple keywords using PocketSphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx)

he says the grammar-file should be something like this to avoid detection of words not in grammar-file:

```
up /1e-1/
down /1e-1/
left /1e-1/
right /1e-1/
forwards /1e-1/
backwards /1e-1/
```

....but it doesnt work if it is exactly  like this. I can do it like this:

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar digits;
public <digits> =   /1e-1/ left |
                    /1e-1/ right;
```

but this doesnt change anything, neither does /1.0/ change anything. It keeps detecting false words as left/right.

Putting the threshold on the right side of each word (like the author) leads to app-crashing.

Can someone help me on this?

**UPDATE:**

i solved it, by using addKeywordSearch in the function setupRecognizer(File assetsDir). It was still like in the PocketSphinx-Demo addGrammarSearch in my case. For completeness (just like the setupRecognizer function of the author of the linked question):

```
private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir)
{
    File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");

    recognizer = defaultSetup().setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
                               .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
                               .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f)
                               .getRecognizer();

    recognizer.addListener(this);

    File digitsGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/digits.gram");
    recognizer.addKeywordSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);
}
```

it then works if the grammar file looks (also like the author posted) **exactly** like this:

```
up /1e-1/
down /1e-1/
left /1e-1/
right /1e-1/
forwards /1e-1/
backwards /1e-1/
```

Comment: i have problem in pocket shpinx   post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916938/offline-voice-recognition-android-taking-unwanted-voice