# Offline voice recognition android taking unwanted voice

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx-android

I have did a lot for research and tried offline pocket sphinx but it is taking surrounding voice it is taking and reacting my app differently. Is there any Google offline app for above kitkat 4.4.. i am trying it from 2 week. Thank for your valuable answer.

**Details:** When the activity starts first text has to read the content (Text to speech) after it complete, reading voice recognition has to take voice and as per command ex: (next, previous, forward, option, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc). As per command it has to recognize and react to it in onresult method.

**Error:** i am getting error after taking some voice

```
06-18 19:54:00.159: V/onBeginningOfSpeech(3360): onBeginningOfSpeech
06-18 19:54:01.024: V/onPartialResult(3360): option
06-18 19:54:01.109: I/cmusphinx(3360): INFO: fsg_search.c(843): 105 frames, 5333 HMMs (50/fr), 7748 senones (73/fr), 371 history entries (3/fr)
06-18 19:54:01.110: I/SpeechRecognizer(3360): Stop recognition
06-18 19:54:01.110: E/cmusphinx(3360): ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 913: Final result does not match the grammar in frame 105
06-18 19:54:01.111: V/onPartialResult-->(3360): option
06-18 19:54:01.111: V/onResult(3360): onResult
```

[Android Hive offline link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)

But if I turn off internet it is not working offline.

In pocketsphinx it is not reacting to correct word. If I say "next" it takes near by voice content of another appends the "key" and it gives me lot of problem. Is there any solution or library to use offline. Any offline google offline voice support.

Below is my code what is tried

```java
package com.example.sample1;

import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;

public class Sam extends Activity implements RecognitionListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    /* Named searches allow to quickly reconfigure the decoder */

    private static final String DIGITS_SEARCH = "digits";

    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;
    private TextView caption_text;
    private TextView result_text;
    ArrayList<String> result1;
    private Button buttonLeft;
    private Button buttonRight;
    int count = 0;
    private ArrayList<DataAnswer> dummyListTemp;
    private ArrayList<DataAnswer> dummyList;
    AnswerDataAdapter listAdapter = null;
    int conteo = 0;
    Handler a = new Handler();
    private TextToSpeech tts; 
    String readIt ="";

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        Log.v("onCreate", "onCreate");

        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);

        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);
        caption_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text);
        result_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
    //  listViewAnswer = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAnswer);
        buttonRight  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        buttonLeft  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
        result_text.setText("Result --->: ");

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);  

        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");

        String text = "World is full of chanllenge"; 
        //Speakes the text first and then after comple reading text voice recoginzation must start
        speakOut(text);




        buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //onClickRight();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });

        buttonLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //onClickLeft();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task
        //if(!tts.isSpeaking()) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Assets assets = new Assets(Sam.this);
                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                    Log.v("AsyncTask", "AsyncTask");
                    setupRecognizer(assetDir);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
                Log.v("onPostExecute", "onPostExecute");
                try{
                    if (result != null) {
                        //caption_text.setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to init recognizer ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        FireRecognition();
                        //switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
        recognizer.cancel();
        recognizer.shutdown();

        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public void FireRecognition(){
        Log.d("Recognition","Recognition Started");
        //caption_text.setText("Recognition Started!");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recognition Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        recognizer.stop();
        //recognizer.startListening("digits");

    }

    /**
     * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
     * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
     * for final result in onResult.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        try {
            //Log.v("onPartialResult", "onPartialResult");
            if (hypothesis == null)
                return;
            Log.v("onPartialResult", hypothesis.getHypstr().toString());

            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
            if(recognizer !=null)
                recognizer.stop();

            caption_text.setText("Partial result -->: " + text);

            Log.v("onPartialResult-->", text);

            //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        try{
            Log.v("onResult", "onResult");
            //  result_text.setText("");
            if (hypothesis != null) {
                String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);

                if(text.toLowerCase().equals("next")) {
                    result_text.setText("Result --->: " + text);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(text.toLowerCase().equals("previous")) {
                    result_text.setText("Result --->: " + text);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if(text.toLowerCase().trim().equals("option one".toLowerCase().trim())) {
                    result_text.setText("Result --->: " + text);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    result_text.setText("Result --->: " + text);
                } else if(text.toLowerCase().trim().equals("option two".toLowerCase().toString())) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(text.toLowerCase().trim().equals("option three".toLowerCase().toString())) {
                    result_text.setText("Result --->: " + text);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(text.toLowerCase().trim().equals("option four".toLowerCase().toString())) {
                    result_text.setText("Result --->: " + text);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " No Access:--" + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




                Log.v("onResult-->", text);
                if(recognizer != null)              
                    recognizer.startListening("digits");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.v("onBeginningOfSpeech", "onBeginningOfSpeech");

    }

    /**
     * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
     */
    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.v("onEndOfSpeech", "onEndOfSpeech");

        if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(DIGITS_SEARCH))
            switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
    }


    private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
        Log.v("switchSearch", "switchSearch--->" + searchName);
        recognizer.stop();

        // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
        if (searchName.equals(DIGITS_SEARCH))
            recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);
        /* else
            recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);*/

        /* String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
        caption_text.setText(caption);*/
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {

        // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
        // of different kind and switch between them
        Log.v("setupRecognizer", "setupRecognizer");
        recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

                // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)

                // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f) //1e-20f 1e-45f

                // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile
                // .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);

        /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
         * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
         */

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        // recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);



        // Create grammar-based search for digit recognition
        File digitsGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "digits.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);

    }



    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
        Log.v("onError", "onError");
        //caption_text.setText(error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeout() {
        Log.v("onTimeout", "onTimeout");
        switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(recognizer != null)
                            recognizer.startListening("digits");
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {  

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);  


            Log.i("Success", "Completed");

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA  || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {  
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");  
            } else {  
                //buttonSpeak.setEnabled(true);  
                //  speakOut();  
                String text = " No Voice Found".toString();
                Log.i("else", "else");
                // speakOut(text);  
            }  

        } else {  
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");  
        }  

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void speakOut(String text) {
        if(tts.isSpeaking()) {
            //recognizer.stop();
        }
        //  String text =  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).getText().toString();
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);

        Log.i("Speaking-->", "****" + tts.isSpeaking());

    } 



}
```

And in digit.gram

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar digits;

<digit> = option one |
          option two |
          option three |
          option four |
          back |
          previous |
          next;

public <digits> = <digit>+;
```

Above is my code if any one worked on it please let me know the solution
Here is my xml quiz.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewAnswer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="301dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:childDivider="#334455" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:text="Next" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Previous" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#556677" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/caption_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/result_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#443399" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:**

if u are using **addKeywordSearch**

```
File digitsGrammar = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "digits.gram");
recognizer.addKeywordSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);
```

then in digit.gram write only

```
 option one /1e-1/
 option two /1e-1/
 option three /1e-1/
 option four /1e-1/
 back /1e-1/
 previous /1e-1/
 next /1e-1/
```

**or**

if you are using  **addGrammarSearch**

```
 File digitsGrammar = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "digits.gram");
 recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);
```

then in digit.gram

```
#JSGF V1.0;

grammar digits;

<digit> = option one |
      option two |
      option three  |
      option four |
      back  |
      previous |
      next;

     public <digits> = <digit>+;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use keyword spotting mode instead of grammar mode for continuous listening

You can find example here:

[Recognizing multiple keywords using PocketSphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx)

Comment: How to do it. can i get any sample  related to it.

Comment: instead of  recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);  i have to add  recognizer.addKeywordSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);  rite. Then what i need to edit in digit.gram

Comment: Updated above digit.gram is it write way i have to change for keywordsearch

Comment: You can find example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx

Comment: i have tried that example but it showing error in digit.gram and jsgf error.. this is correct way to edit in digit.gram #JSGF V1.0;

grammar digits;

<digit> = option one /1.0/ |
          option two /1.0/ |
          option three /1.0/ |
          option four /1.0/ |
          back /1.0/ |
          previous /1.0/ |
          next;

public <digits> = <digit>+;

Comment: You incorrectly used grammar for keyword spotting, it should not be a grammar but just a list of keyphrases. You can find the reference in the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Android M, you can use EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE when you create the recognizer intent.