# offline google voice recognition in android for lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

i am working on google offline voice recognition for latest version.
I have followed [Android hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/) but it is not working offline.

I have made research on pocket sphinx but it takes side voice (near surrounding voice) here i updated [pocket sphinx research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916938/offline-voice-recognition-android-taking-unwanted-voice/30948016?noredirect=1#comment49941321_30948016) but no good result.
I have heard that for latest os lollipop offline voice recognition support but there is no sample. If any one worked on it please help me and it helps lot like me who works on it. Sorry for bad english.

**Detail:-**

When I start the application the voice recognition should start and listen. When the recognizer matches some words then my app will do different actions accordingly.

Comment: Can i know reason for down vote.. Down voted person can u answer.