# New .gram file in pocketSphinx

Tags: android, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx-android

[Recognizing multiple keywords using PocketSphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx)

I have a working on project as mentioned above and I have listed new set of words in my digit.gram file.

My doubt regarding this recognition is that I want to recognize a new ".gram" file instead of saying digits, which calls the digits.gram .

For example, instead of saying digits, I can say robot, then robot.gram will be called, how to make that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define multiple rules and combine them with a pipe. Like this:

```
<digits> = one | two | three;
<robot> = robot;
public <command> = <digit> | <robot>;
```