# Android Continuous Speech Recognition using pocketsphinx. How to clear hypothesis?

Tags: android, pocketsphinx-android

I am Currently working on a project to implement offline continuous speech recognition using pocketsphinx. I have developed it to the point where it recognizes the keyword I say, however the hypothesis in `onPartialResults()` and `onResults()` is not cleared and the words keep appending to the string. Therefore the code ahead keeps getting called infinitely.

Using `hypothesis.setHypstr("");` or `hypothesis.delete();` doesn't do anything.

I want it to wait in the background, whenever I say the keyword, it runs the code and wait in the background again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear hypothesis you need to stop recognizer and start listening again:

```
   recognizer.cancel()
   recognizer.startListening(searchName)
```

Check the code here for example

[Recognizing multiple keywords using PocketSphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx)

Comment: while listening same searchName again, hypothesis is not getting clear. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sure, but you need to provide the required information. What exactly are you doing and what is in logcat output. You need to create a separate question, not spam in an old one