# About Android Speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I use RecognizerIntent and implement the RecognitionListener and implement all of its call back methodsas to do voice commands.
And I try to adjust the parameters EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS,EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS and EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS to decrease the listen time but it seems not work.
How can I do ?

Another question is about the recognition speed.  I just have five voice commands in my system. But I need to pass and wait for the recognition result every time. Can I preprocess something or other methods to accelerate the recognition speed?

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself. First you say you want dictation, then you say you have just 5 voice commands.

Comment: Sorry!  I fixed this typing error.

Comment: For your first question, setting EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS , affects the minimum duration, not the maximum.

Comment: Your first statement is that you are using the SpeechRecognizer class directly, and your next statements suggests you are using an Intent. Can you specify which one it is?

Comment: There is a class called VoiceInteractor, which is introduced in Marshmallow, which probably will be able to handle multiple voice commands locally, but I don't know if it can at this time.

Comment: Hi @geokavel, thanks for your answers. I already fixed my first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the task you described it make sense to use closed-dictionary ASR system, such as [pocketsphinx-android](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android). You will be able to fine-tune pre- and post-speech wait intervals as well as speed-up the decoding as the recognition happens on-board rather than  going back and forth to the cloud.

Comment: Hi @Alexander Solovets, Thanks for your advices. I'm trying to use pocketsphinx-android to do speech recognition. I run another demo program from [Pocketsphinx on Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid).
It's good to recognize. But how can I set multiple keywords by using function call "addKeywordSearch"?
I found the post [Recognizing multiple keywords using PocketSphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx), but it is not work.

Comment: I solved it. It's my mistake. I tuned the keywords threshold then it can run.

Comment: But why it output many results when I just said one keywords or even did not say anything? Can I just get one result from each recognition?
Sorry for lots of questions.

Comment: I think from this point should better ask questions on the [cmu sphinx forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/) providing portions of the source code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I am looking for some solution on the forum.

David

Comment: Do you mind helping me? I am trying to simply recognize the word "hello" using pocketsphinx. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388720/cant-start-service-speech-recog