# hypothesis parameter pocketsphinx

Tags: pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I use Pocketsphinx in my Android app. I recognize speech using addGrammarSearch (String name, File file). When there is noise around, then Pocketsphinx catches it and recognizes it as a word or phrase from the grammar. But the word was not uttered. Is there any parameter in the hypothesis, which shows how much the recognized sound is like a word from a grammar? What method can I get this parameter?
I want to filter out the recognized sound, which has a low value, that is, it does not look like a word in the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748113/recognizing-multiple-keywords-using-pocketsphinx) has an approach you may find useful -- that is, if you can tolerate using a keyword list instead of a full grammar. (Note that keywords do not have to be single words.) With `SpeechRecognizer.addKeywordSearch()`, you can set "thresholds" for each keyword, which is critical to reducing false positives.

The thresholds are usually found via experimentation. The closer it is to `1e-50`, the more likely you are to get a false positive. The closer it is to `1e0`, the more likely you are to miss a valid utterance.